# How to edit a slicer to call functions using CRUD?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I can’t figure out how to call functions in components, passing them as parameters. For example, to receive a full tour or removal. So that it is updated on the backend and in the store.

This is my API:

```js
import { TourType } from "../../types/types";
import { api } from "./api";

export const tourAPI = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getAllTour: builder.query<{ message: string; data: TourType[] }, void>({
      query: () => ({
        url: "/tour",
        method: "GET",
      }),
    }),
    getTourByTourNumber: builder.query<TourType, string>({
      query: (number) => ({
        url: `/tour/number/${number}`,
        method: "GET",
      }),
    }),
    editTour: builder.mutation<string, TourType>({
      query: (tour) => ({
        url: `/tour`,
        method: "PUT",
        body: tour,
      }),
    }),
    removeTour: builder.mutation<string, number>({
      query: (number) => ({
        url: `/tour`,
        method: "DELETE",
        body: { number: number },
      }),
    }),
    addTour: builder.mutation<TourType, TourType>({
      query: (tour) => ({
        url: "/tour/create",
        method: "POST",
        body: tour,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetAllTourQuery,
  useGetTourByTourNumberQuery,
  useEditTourMutation,
  useRemoveTourMutation,
  useAddTourMutation,
} = tourAPI;

export const {
  endpoints: {
    getAllTour,
    getTourByTourNumber,
    editTour,
    removeTour,
    addTour
  },
} = tourAPI;
```

And my slice:

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { TourType } from "../../types/types";
import { tourAPI } from "../api/tourAPI";
import { RootState } from "../../store/store";

interface InitialState {
  tour: TourType[];
  loading: boolean;
}

const initialState: InitialState = {
  tour: [],
  loading: true,
};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "tour",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logout: () => initialState,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      tourAPI.endpoints.getAllTour.matchFulfilled,
      (state, action) => {
        state.tour = action.payload.data;
      }
    );
  },
});

export default slice.reducer;

export const selectTour = (state: RootState): TourType[] => state.tour.tour;
```

Now I get all the tours this way:

```
const { data, isLoading } = useGetAllTourQuery();
```

I add it like this:

```js
const [addTour] = useAddTourMutation();
... 

const handleAddTour = async (data: TourType) => {
  try {
    await addTour(data).unwrap();
  } catch (err) {
    const maybeError = isErrorWithMessage(err);
    
    if (maybeError) {
      setError(err.data.message);
    } else {
      setError("Error");
    }
  }
};
```

The tour is added but the store is not updated and a new one does not appear on the page.

Comment: I'm curious, why the tour state slice in addition to the API slice? What is the use case for the duplicate tour data in the store?

Comment: I’m just switching to redux with slicers, I admit that there is a lot of unnecessary code... I will need to do refactoring, in any case. Could you explain how you would do it? I don’t quite understand where the duplication is happening?

Comment: The duplication is the cached query state and this additional tour state slice. That tour slice isn't necessary really.

Comment: Oh, I'll try to figure it out, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem that you have done something to update the store.

You have added the extra reducer to your state, which updates the state on successful result of getAllTour query, but you haven't added an extra reducer for addTour.

You should make changes in your slice:

```
const slice = createSlice({
  name: "tour",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logout: () => initialState,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      tourAPI.endpoints.getAllTour.matchFulfilled,
      (state, action) => {
         state.tour = action.payload.data;
      }
    );
    builder.addMatcher(
      tourAPI.endpoints.addTour.matchFulfilled,
      (state, action) => {
        state.tour.push(action.payload.data);
      }
    );
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cache tags to provide & invalidate cache results. Queries provide tags and mutations invalidate them to trigger subscribed queries to refetch automatically.

See [Automated Re-fetching](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching), and specifically [Invalidating Cache Data](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching#invalidating-cache-data)

Example:

```js
export const tourAPI = api
  .enhanceEndpoints({
    // Only need this enhancement if tags not specified in `createApi`
    addTagTypes: ["tours", "tour"],
  })
  .injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
      getAllTour: builder.query<{ message: string; data: TourType[] }, void>({
        query: () => ({
          url: "/tour",
          method: "GET",
        }),
        providesTags: ["tours"], // <-- query provides tags
      }),
      getTourByTourNumber: builder.query<TourType, string>({
        query: (number) => ({
          url: `/tour/number/${number}`,
          method: "GET",
        }),
        providesTags: (result, error, tourNumber) => [
          { type: "tour", id: tourNumber }
        ],
      }),
      editTour: builder.mutation<string, TourType>({
        query: (tour) => ({
          url: `/tour`,
          method: "PUT",
          body: tour,
        }),
        invalidatesTags: (result, error, tourNumber) => [
          "tours",
          { type: "tour", id: tourNumber }
        ],
      }),
      removeTour: builder.mutation<string, number>({
        query: (number) => ({
          url: `/tour`,
          method: "DELETE",
          body: { number: number },
        }),
        invalidatesTags: (result, error, tourNumber) => [
          "tours",
          { type: "tour", id: tourNumber }
        ],
      }),
      addTour: builder.mutation<TourType, TourType>({
        query: (tour) => ({
          url: "/tour/create",
          method: "POST",
          body: tour,
        }),
        invalidatesTags: ["tours"], // <-- invalidates query tags
      }),
    }),
  });
```

When the `addTour` trigger from the `useAddTourMutation` hook runs successfully, it will invalidate the `"tours"` cache tag. The `getAllTour` query endpoint that provides the `"tours"` tag will automatically refetch its data and trigger subscribed components running the `useGetAllTourQuery` to rerender with the updated query results.